# Is it possible to create/manage Roles using a .yaml file?

Tags: drupal-8

I'm trying to secure some REST URLs that are present in my **ApiController.php** so that users with certain privileges can access these REST APIs.
I created some users and assigned them with some Roles using the below link:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/user-concept.html

As you can see, I'm creating roles in Drupal Admin following below steps:

***Drupal UI → People → Role → Add New Role                   // line 4***

After that, I added a few permissions in permission.yml:

**xyz.permissions.yml**

```
edit permission:
  title: 'edit permission'
```

And updated routing file to secure APIs:

**xyz.routing.yml**

```
xyz.update:
  path: '/update'
    _controller: 'ApiController::update'
    _permission: 'edit permission'
```

This is working fine. i.e. users that have "edit permission" can access URL "/update". 
But, I don't want to do step on line 4 rather I would like to use some .yaml file to create Roles.

Is it possible to create/manage Roles using a .yaml file?

Answer (score 1):

Role creation can be done through install and uninstall process of module but not possible through Yaml file.